# postgres is not inserting the identity column into lastid +1 after using the sequence

Tags: postgresql

I have a table(Table_1) with Identity column(id) in postgres 12.Table_1 is already having data and id column is in sequence like 2,4,6,8,10 etc.,(in even number) upto 1000.Now from front end application , I am trying to input data which should sit in the table as 1001st record.
I tried to create sequence in below 2 methods but no luck.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS table_seq_id; 
SELECT setval('table_seq_id', (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM table_1), false);
ALTER TABLE table_1 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_seq_id');

select max(id) from table_1 into newid;
IF newid is null THEN newid = 1; else newid = newid + 1; END IF;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS table_seq_id; 
alter sequence  'table_seq_id' restart  with ' || newid;
ALTER TABLE table_1 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_seq_id');
```

It is trying to insert value from 1 not from 1001.For odd numbers, the values are inserted and for even numbers , the below error is thrown
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_Table_1"
DETAIL:  Key ("id")=(24) already exists.
SQL state: 23505

In this error, the number is shown as 24 and again if i insert , it will insert in 25 and throws the same error for 26.

Please input your suggestions.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public."table_1" ( 
    "id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ), 
    "name" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "pk_public.table_1" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"), 
    CONSTRAINT "fk_public.table_1_public.Tenants_TenantId" 
        FOREIGN KEY 
            ("TenantId") REFERENCES public."Tenants" ("TenantId") 
        MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
)
```

Comment: Please include the table description/schema.

Comment: Below is my table structure.
CREATE TABLE public."table_1"
(
    "id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
 "name" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
  CONSTRAINT "pk_public.table_1" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_public.table_1_public.Tenants_TenantId" FOREIGN KEY ("TenantId")
        REFERENCES public."Tenants" ("TenantId") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: While creating the table structure I have given the Identity column as "Generated by Default As Identity" .But as I said , it is not inserting after the lastvalue. So I used sequence to overcome the issue.But it is working when i drop the identity and tried to insert the value after altering the sequence restart with Newid..

Comment: The point is why should i drop the identity for inserting the values after the lastid and Generated By Default As Identity function is meant for generating the values in identity column sequentially.Why it is trying to insert values in already inserted id. In my case in even numbers id and throws error.

Comment: Added table definition to question to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

`GENERATED BY DEFAULT` allows for the user to add values to the column that do not come from the sequence. I suspect there is something else that was was supplying the even numbers. Now that process is not supplying the numbers and the sequence attached to the identity is, starting from 1. So it works for the odd numbers that where not present before, but not for the even numbers. You can have the identity column restart at new value by doing:

`ALTER TABLE public."table_1"  ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1001;`

or whatever number is max(id) + 1